# Bot sending an interactive google map to Telegram user

Tags: telegram-bot

A bot wants to send a map with specific lat/lng point to a Telegram user. When clicked that map should lead user to an interactive map version.

I saw one bot (SberbankBot) can do that, but I need to know how exactly.

I'm using Python 2.7 + `telepot` library.

[image]

Comment: This is location, see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation

Answer (score 6):

As [@mymedia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5000805/mymedia) pointed out in comments, you can use [`sendLocation`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation) method of *Telegram Bot APi*, and using `telepot`:

```
bot.sendLocation(chat_id, latitude=lat, longitude=lon);
```